# Finagle thrift client server implementation in Java using Netty

Tags: java, twitter, thrift, netty, finagle

Was just going through Finagle homepage "http://twitter.github.com/finagle/". It says we can write java implementation of netty with thrift using Finagale. I tried searching for examples for the same, but couldn't find one. All examples are in scala.
Can someone provide me with pointers for its Java implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've written one up here: [finagle-java-example](https://github.com/jghoman/finagle-java-example) that demonstrates writing a thrift-based Finagle server in Java using blocking and non-blocking calls.

Comment: It seems that they've updated the API and deprecated the use of .ServerIface. I'm having trouble getting the new API working in Java, though. Any idea how to use this .FinagleClient syntax?